# Why does my iPhone shift the screen downwards?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility

My iPhone sometimes shift the view down by about 1/3 of the screen in order to reveal... nothing, just the blurry background image.

How can I prevent this from happening?

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature called **reachability**. It's built into iPhones so you can reach stuff with one hand.

You can disable it by going to <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Accessibility</kbd> -> <kbd>Touch</kbd> and *toggle*  <kbd>Reachability</kbd>.

Also, if you want to know how to use it, [tap the home button twice (some call this gesture a wiggle)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/174255/5472) without clicking it or [swipe down on the home bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298225/5472).